# MySQL update string in string set

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a table namely `all_products`. In which tags are stored in the comma-separated form. Like `tag1, tag2, tag3`. Now if the user updates the tag then I need to update the tag value in this set also. This table is used for caching purpose so can not normalize it. What I've done is

```
UPDATE all_products SET tags = replace(tags,
         'Tag2', 'Tag2 Updated')
WHERE find_in_set('Tag2', tags)
```

The issue in the above query is if there are two tags namely `tag2` and `tag22` in the same row then the query will update both. I want it to update `tag2` only.

Is there any way by which I can update the exact tag only?

Comment: @Nick correct, but the `replace` will update both tags if same `tag2` and `tag22` will be present in the column.

Comment: I see what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

Use the operator LIKE:

```
UPDATE all_products 
SET tags = trim(both ',' from replace(concat(',', tags, ','), ',Tag2,', ',Tag2 Updated,'))
WHERE concat(',', tags, ',') like '%,Tag2,%'
```

This code assumes that there are no spaces between the tags and the commas.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mBuKHnWznG17UCnveoxgeC/0).

```
create table all_products(tags varchar(100)); 
insert into all_products(tags) values
('a,b,c'),                                       
('a,Tag2,c'),
('Tag2,b,Tag22');
```

Results:

```
| tags                 |
| -------------------- |
| a,b,c                |
| a,Tag2 Updated,c     |
| Tag2 Updated,b,Tag22 |
```

Edit
As of @Nick's recomendation, you can use [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE find_in_set('Tag2', tags) > 0
```

Comment: See OPs response to my (now deleted) comment. find_in_set isn't the problem

Comment: @Nick see the demo in my answer.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. It wasn't me that downvoted but I'll compensate...

Comment: Yes that was the problem and of course the downvoter did not see the edit.

Comment: Note I would stick with `FIND_IN_SET`, it's the perfect function for this.

Comment: @Nick yes it is better in mysql. I included your recommendation.